# Cloudflare "Login with SSO" preventing Dashboard Access

Tags: cloudflare

I have a GitHub Pages site working with CloudFlare and, from time to time, I need to Purge my Cache. In order to do so, as you know, I need to log into my account.

However, as I write this, I'm unable to do so. When I access `https://dash.cloudflare.com/login`, as soon as I type my mail, the password field becomes disabled and the blue "Log in" button now says "Log in with SSO", which I don't know what it is.

Clicking this button redirects me to a Page very similar to an OAuth Authorization from, apparently, an app from `tpimenta.cloudflareaccess.com` which I don't recognize.

I tried contacting support, but after reading the extensive docs, I wasn't able to solve my problem and when I try to Contact Support directly I'm redirected to the login page <_<

Posting anything in Cloudflare's forums is kinda pointless to me, as when I had trouble in the past, nobody answered within 15 days and the topic ended up being closed.

I believe it's worth mentioning that, recently, I was looking for a way to expose my local development online and found Cloudflare's **Cloudflared** (formerly ARGO, I believe) and, after some research, trial and error, I managed to create a tunnel. I don't really know if this has anything to do with this problem but, in any case, these were the steps I took:

```
cloudflared tunnel login
cloudflared tunnel create preview
cloudflared tunnel route dns preview tunnel.myclouflaresite.com
cloudflared tunnel run --url localhost:1313 preview
hugo server --baseURL=https://myclouflaresite.com --liveReloadPort=443 --appendPort=false
```

> The last step is not related to Cloudflared. I only mentioned this because up to Step #3, while the tunnel works, nothing other than an expected Bad Gateway message appears

Thank you for your time